# Where to find definition of CeCreateDatabaseWithProps

Tags: database, embedded, windows-ce

According to msdn it should be in windbase.h but it is not available instead it is in windbase_edb.h but cordll.lib is linked with windabase.h only. So, i want to know is there any method by which CeCreateDatabaseWithProps can be linked with a appropraite library?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, coredll.lib isn't linked with *any* header.

CeCreateDatabaseWithProps is defined in windbase_edb.h in the SDK, so you can include the declaration from there. If you look at coredll.lib with dumpbin, you'll see that the linker definition is in there (at ordinal 1897).

If your linker isn't finding it first make sure you're targeting the right SDK (it's WinMo 6 only). If it still refuses to link, then manually declare it as an extern at the top of a code page.